# builder.Prompts.choice get options as buttons

Tags: botframework

`builder.Prompts.choice` component is not rendering the options when listStyle is present in the options?

For example:

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Please confirm your choice", "Yes|No", {listStyle:"buttons"});
```

renders only "Please confirm your choice", but not the options.

Removing the `{listStyle}` option, shows "Yes|No" inline with the text.

Any suggestion on how do we work around this issue?

Comment: For more informations about listStyle please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt#promptschoice

Answer (score 4):

I don't think "buttons" maps to the correct style, instead you could try:

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Please confirm your choice", "Yes|No", {listStyle:3});
```

Or better still use:

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Please confirm your choice", "Yes|No", {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
```

You also need to make sure you're using a channel that's compatible with buttons (SMS and some others don't display them).